# Как письменно передать "подожди" со "съеденными" буквами

Tags: общие-вопросы

Довольно часто приходится слышать что-то вроде: "пожжи", "пожьжи", "пажьи". Полагаю, что более или менее точный вариант должен быть один. Но который? (не обязательно выбирать из предложенных, но мне вот чаще всего в жизни попадаются варианты, где "д" вообще не звучит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не слышал без Д, но допускаю и такой вариант. Сам говорю то [ж'ж'], то [жд']. Первый вариант — старомосковское произношение, которое я бы передал как [падаж'ж'и]. Если Д действительно не выговаривают иногда (не знаю, насколько это правильно), получается [паж'ж'и]. Сам так обычно не говорю, но слышал то же [ж'ж'] в словах *осуждённый, Рождество, рождение,* ну и, конечно же, *дожди* (так тоже говорю всегда). Те три слова стесняюсь так произносить, потому что такое произношение слышу очень редко, не хочется выделяться сильно.

Comment: А после первой "Ж" мягкий знак не нужен?

Comment: Нужен. Просто я вместо него поставил ' как смягчение.